# if repeating response in foreach in while loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, while-loop, do-while

I have an if in a foreach in a while loop. I'm searching for a string in another string of text.

```
$base = 'someurl';
$url = $base;
while(1){
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    $more = $json->next_page;
    $next = $json->next_page_number;

    if($more){
        $url = $base.'&page='.$next;
    }else{
        break;
    }

    foreach($json as $data){
        $c = $data->text; // search in
        $s = 'string';
        $t = 'prefix1'.$s; // search for
        $m = 'prefix2'.$s; // search for

        if( (strpos($c, $t) || strpos($c, $m)) !== false ){
            echo '<p>hello, i found one or more ($t and/or $m) of the search criteria in the text string $c .</p>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the echo from the if statement twice  :(

What I want to achieve is to only make the echo happen ONCE, if $t and/or $m is present in $c.

Comment: as far as I see it, that line will echo indefinitely because of the `while(1);`

Comment: @Jerodev - Yea, there's an if/break in the original loop, my bad. See updated code  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so found a working solution for my particular problem (although I'm still not clear as to why the if statements response got echoed twice?).

Using preg_match instead of strpos gave me a working solution :)

```
if(preg_match('('.$t.'|'.$m.')', $c) === 1){
    // tis' the truth echoed thru eternity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess you're receiving the echo twice because you found 2 records that match your condition, is that possible?

If so, and you only want to check that your condition matches at least once on the array, you could break the foreach after you found your first match, like:

```
if( ( strpos( $c, $t ) || strpos( $c, $m ) ) !== false ){
    echo '<p>hello, I was told I was true</p>';
    break;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I already tried that... just forgot to put it in the desc. See updated version (still same result).

Comment: So then, you're getting a match in 2 different "pages" from the URL in the while loop (not the for). Why don't you just print the `$url` and `$c` when you get the match so you can see what's matching where?